# Add non-standard attribute to a select tag with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to create a select element through JavaScript and I want to set an attribute to it called `data-placeholder`.

How can we assign non-standard attributes with JavaScript without the browser complaining with:

```
Uncaught referenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
```

Code that cause the error:

```
select1.data-placeholder="Choose ...";
```

Comment: Show your JavaScript, you did something wrong, but we can't see what.

Comment: Peter Pajchl has the answer - that was it

Comment: Still would have been nice to see the code that caused the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it says with javascript not jquery...

```
yourElement.setAttribute('data-placeholder','value');
```

Comment: Short, concise and beautiful. Can you please send me a link of this documentation?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pretty simple non-jQuery way to achieve this;

```
var el = document.createElement('select');
el.setAttribute('data-placeholder', 'placeholder value');
document.body.appendChild(el);​
```

I've created a very simple [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jasonmerino/yN833/1/) to demonstrate it.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score -1):

JQuery makes this easy:

```
$("<select></select>").attr("data-placeholder", "value").appendTo($element);
```

Comment: +1, you could also write `$("<select></select>").data("placeholder", "value") // ...`

Comment: @epascarello - There doesn't need to be one, it's still a solution.

Comment: It is like suggesting a person use a hammer to open a window. It is a tool that does the job.

Comment: AND you should be using `data()` and not `attr()`. ;p

Comment: @epascarello - so by your logic, I can't suggest they type on a keyboard because they haven't tagged it? Genius right there..

Comment: What does `$("<select></select>")` do? Does it create a select element? I already have a select variable **var select1 = document.createElement('select');** How do I add custom attribute to select1?

Comment: @MatthewAbbott the question is if the person is using any javascript library such as jquery...

Comment: @Florent `.data()` doesn't add an attribute that isn't already there.  It just sets internal fields within the DOM element, with that field's _default_ value _read_ from the attribute.